# Intellij Idea 14 can't find javascript files linked in html when open in browser

Tags: html, intellij-idea

I've spent a lot of time searching for answer, and decided to post the correct answer after I had received it from Idea support.

The problem was when I opened from Idea a html file with linked javascript files in a browser, it used the 'http://' to open this file in its own app server. In this case only js files located in the same folder as the html could be loaded.
In the Idea 12 the 'file://' protocol is used by default, and all scripts could be loaded successfully.

The answer:
To open html via 'file://' in the Idea 14 you should hold shift while opening through a browser.